# passing variable value into where condition laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Im trying to make where condition with variable value like this.

> RekapController@show

```
public function show($tanggal)
{
    $absen = Absen::where('DATE(created_at)', '=', $tanggal)
                    ->get();
}
```

[image: My Table Structure]

But when i run my code, it show an error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE(created_at)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `absen` where `DATE(created_at)` = 2017-08-17)

Thanks

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used

```
$absen = Absen::where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d/%M/%Y')"), '=', $tanggal)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `DATE(created_at)` inside where will search `DATE(created_at)` for table columns but there is no such column and it doesn't know as a sql function so you can try in following way,

```
$absen = Absen::select('absen.*',DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'))
                ->where('date', '=', $tanggal)
                ->get();
```

Here you will get date of the `created_at` column at first and then compare inside where clause.

Hope you understand.